# Use safety filters even if after applied intval?

Tags: filters, customization

I have some values to save into postmeta and usermeta table. Before save, I already done this: `$value = intval($value)` . I think this is enough. But I see some plugins still use filters on those numbers. I want to make sure that I can do with `intval` and without safety filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`intval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) behaves sometimes a little bit counter-intuitive when then value has leading zeros or when it is a mathematic expression. The result should always be **safe**, but is not always what you might **expect**.

A simple example:

```
intval( '9223372036854775808' );
```

will never return this value, because even 64 bit system cannot handle such a large number. You get `9223372036854775807` on a 64 bit system and `2147483647` on 32 bit.

But if you use:

```
preg_match( '~\d+~', '9223372036854775808', $matches );
```

`$matches[0]` will return this number unchanged.

So, it depends on the values you expect.

Comment: I see. I will only use it on tiny numbers, 1, -1, and 0. so, that should be fine. Anyway, it's interesting to learn this behavior.